# jQuery get Width of Listelements in one Row

Tags: jquery

how can I calculate the Size of all Listelements in one Row?
I get only one Size. But what I need is that following.
When I resize the Browserwindow and 4 Listelemts are in one Row, or 2 etc. I need always the Size from all Elements in one Row.

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>

<div class="result"></span>

$('li').each(function() {
   var widthE = $('li').width();
    console.log(widthE);
});
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v127zvy0/7/

Comment: If you do `$('ul').width();` this will return the width of the `ul` which is also the width of how wide a row is in your case except for the last row if the number of item in each row is uneven. If you don't care for the uneven row then you can just use that. If you need every single row, then it's just doing math to see how wide is the `ul` then divided by your `li` width and eventually figuring out how many list item is in the last row to get that width

Comment: ok. say my ul has 532px. My li has 300px. When I divide 532/300 = 1,773. I think thats wrong or i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: It's complicated to explain, but basically if you have the width of ul and li, you can figure out how many li can fit in ul, then you can figure out how many rows there will be (if you can fit 2 in one row and you have 5 items then you know it's 3 rows). Lastly you can figure out how many items the last row has. You also need to add the spaces between each li. What are you trying to achieve, there might be a simpler way to do what you want

Comment: sounds very complicated. i need, the size of every li in one row. and with this width i resize an image...

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? What is the final goal? Are you trying to resize this image for each row, as in each row has its own image?

Comment: No I want to resize an Headerimage.

Comment: Then I would imagine getting the width of the `ul` would work since it is most likely based on the width of the longest row which would be any row but the last which is the width of the `ul`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't the width of the UL be the width of a row?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   var rowWidth = $('ul').width();
    console.log(rowWidth);
});
```

Comment: Except the last row if uneven

Comment: hm, the width is wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/v127zvy0/15/: there also calculate the whitespace next to the ul :(

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var widthOfRow = $("ul").width();
});
```

This will give you the width of `ul` which is width of a row in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the Answer is quite easy.

The UL needs `display:inline`

The Fiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/v127zvy0/24/`